# input() and \n characters in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find and replace several lines of plain text in multiple files with input() but when I enter '\n' characters to represent where the new line chars would be in the text, it doesn't find it and doesn't replace it.

I tried to use raw_strings but couldn't get them to work.

Is this a job for regular expressions?

```
python 3.7

import os
import re
import time

start = time.time()
# enter path and check input for standard format
scan_folder = input('Enter the absolute path to scan:\n')
validate_path_regex = re.compile(r'[a-z,A-Z]:\\?(\\?\w*\\?)*')
mo = validate_path_regex.search(scan_folder)
if mo is None:
    print('Path is not valid. Please re-enter path.\n')
    import sys
    sys.exit()
os.chdir(scan_folder)
# get find/replaceStrings, and then confirm that inputs are correct.
find_string = input('Enter the text you wish to find:\n')
replace_string = input('Enter the text to replace:\n')
permission = input('\nPlease confirm you want to replace '
                   + find_string + ' with '
                   + replace_string + ' in ' + scan_folder
                   + ' directory.\n\nType "yes" to continue.\n')
if permission == 'yes':
    change_count = 0
    # Context manager for results file
    with open('find_and_replace.txt', 'w') as results:
        for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(scan_folder):
            for file in files:
                # ignore files that don't endwith '.mpr'
                if os.path.join(root, file).endswith('.mpr'):
                    fullpath = os.path.join(root, file)
                    # context manager for each file opened
                    with open(fullpath, 'r+') as f:
                        text = f.read()
                        # only add to changeCount if find_string is in text
                        if find_string in text:
                            change_count += 1
                        # move cursor back to beginning of the file
                        f.seek(0)
                        f.write(text.replace(find_string, replace_string))
        results.write(str(change_count)
        + ' files have been modified to replace '
        + find_string + ' with ' + replace_string + '.\n')
    print('Done with replacement')
else:
    print('Find and replace has not been executed')
end = time.time()
print('Program took ' + str(round((end - start), 4)) + ' secs to complete.\n')
```

find_string = BM="LS"\nTI="12"\nDU="7"
replace_string = BM="LSL"\nDU="7"

The original file looks like

```
BM="LS"
TI="12"
DU="7"
```

and I would like it to change to

```
BM="LSL"
DU="7"
```

but the file doesn't change.

Comment: Do you mean when you enter `\n` in the terminal as user input? Because that will be interpreted literally as a backslash character and an escape. `input` essentially work by waiting for the user to input *until a line break* and then the string returned does not include the line break.

Comment: `...` does quite a bit of work here. How can the code for opening and iterating the file not be relevant?

Comment: I will also create a new file and then move the file which will give me more flexibility rather than moving the file pointer around.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No, I am typing in the whole string from the file into the terminal including any '\n' chars. I have tried doing '\\n' but it didn't work either .

Comment: @roganjosh I edited the post with the full code.

Comment: @mad_ That is a good idea. I'll have to give that a try and see if I can do it in the future.

Comment: @Protonwaven what do you mean "including \n chars", as in literally pressing the <kbd>return</kbd>  key or typing in `\n`? In either case, it won't work with input, you'll have to use `sys.stdin.read` likely, and terminate your input with an EOF (<kbd>ctrl + D</kbd>)

Comment: Another approach is to manually decode the escape sequences (using the builtin codecs of course). Or even `eval` (or rather, `ast.literal_eval` to be safe), although the eval approaches would be hackier and more brittle, since you'd have to construct a str that represents a valid string literal, taking care of corner cases like quoting issues

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In the terminal I am typing ````\n```` . Well since that won't work I will have to look into ````sys.stdin.read```` and manually decoding the escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

So, the misconception you have is the distinction between *source code*, which understands *escape sequences* like `"this is a string \n with two lines"`, and things like "raw strings" (a concept that doesn't make sense in this context) and the data your are providing as user input. The `input` function basically processes data coming in from the standard input device. When you provide data to standard input, it is being interpreted as a raw bytes and then the `input` function assumes its meant to be text (decoded using whatever your system setting imply). There are two approaches to allow a user to input newlines, the first is to use `sys.stdin`, however, this will require you to provide an EOF, probably using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>:

```
>>> import sys
>>> x = sys.stdin.read()
here is some text and i'm pressing return
to make a new line. now to stop input, press control d>>> x
"here is some text and i'm pressing return\nto make a new line. now to stop input, press control d"
>>> print(x)
here is some text and i'm pressing return
to make a new line. now to stop input, press control d
```

This is not very user-friendly. You have to either pass a newline *and an EOF*, i.e. <kbd>return</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or do <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> *twice*, and this depends on the system, I believe.

A better approach would be to allow the user to input escape sequences, and then decode them yourself:

```
>>> x = input()
I want this to\nbe on two lines
>>> x
'I want this to\\nbe on two lines'
>>> print(x)
I want this to\nbe on two lines
>>> x.encode('utf8').decode('unicode_escape')
'I want this to\nbe on two lines'
>>> print(x.encode('utf8').decode('unicode_escape'))
I want this to
be on two lines
>>>
```